# How to embedded a collection of object with doctrine using attribute #[Embedded]?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Assume we have a simple entity `User` that contains an attribute `$addresses` and this one holds a collection of `Address` objects, how to do this with doctrine ([doc](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/3.1/reference/attributes-reference.html#embeddable)) ?

This is my test :

```
<?php
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Embeddable;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Embedded;

#[Embeddable]
class Address
{
    private string $name;
}

class User
{
    #[Embedded(class: Address::class.'[]')]
    private array $addresses;
}
```

In this example, this doesn't work, because when I retrieve a record of `User`, the property `$address` only represents a bi-dimensional array instead of an array of `Address` instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the definition of `class User`, here is your mistake.

```
private array $address;
```

This should be :

```
private Address $address;
```

Unfortunately, you can’t use Embeddables to implement complex associations and [Doctrine ORM has no plan to do it](https://github.com/doctrine/orm/issues/4291).

For this, you will have to use a more classic `OneToMany` Doctrine association.

Comment: Sorry but I want this property to be a Collection or an array of `Address` object and not a simple object.

Comment: It’s not possible with Embeddables. I edited my answer

Comment: Unfortunately, I think it would be a very interesting feature.